# jumpy animation jquery

Tags: jquery, css, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on this delete button, but for some reason the jquery animation acts a little 'jumpy' when clicking and hovering off the button. I wonder what's causing this..

http://jsfiddle.net/myyn5/3/

[EDIT] thanx a lot guys, check out the final result!: http://jsfiddle.net/myyn5/232/ [/EDIT]

Comment: `.stop()` is your friend whenever doing any animations

Comment: `$.fx.off` doesn't do anything where you use it, since it's a variable that needs a value assigned (i.e. `$.fx.off = true`), and doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do (turns off all animations globally, doesn't stop any currently-running animations). Also, you don't define an `event` argument to your callback, which causes an error.

Comment: This button is actually a replacement for the big ugly popups that show up when you want to delete something important. "Are you sure you want to delete this?" So when leaving the button, it goes back to it's original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with jQuery resizing buttons.

Upon playing with your code in jsfiddle I removed `$fx.off`. Also, as to MrOBrians' point, I added called `.stop()` prior to performing any animation.

`$(function() {

```
$(".custom").on({
    click: function() {
        $("span").stop(true, true).show();
        $(this).animate({
            width: 90
        }, 700, function() {
            $("span").stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '18px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 500, 'swing');
            $(this).addClass("confirm");
            $(this).removeClass("custom");
        })
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       $(this).removeClass("confirm");
        $("span").stop(true, true).animate({
            left: '-12px',
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
            $(".custom").stop(true, true).animate({
                width: 18
            }, 500);
        });
        $(this).addClass("custom");
    }
});
```

});`

Also made some changes to the css as my first thought was that it was the lack of a defined width on the button.

However, I wasn't able to get the button's width from shrinking prior to resizing, even if the button was already at its intended size. It still wanted to jump in before sizing sizing to 90. This was triggering a mouseleave event if the cursor was to positioned at a point on the button causing a hiccup and an unintended jumpy animation.

Anyway I'm not sure if it's a bug in jquery with buttons or if there's somework around. But what I had to do was change the button to a DIV and then everything started playing nice.

`<p>
    <div class="btn btn-danger custom">
        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
        <span>Delete</span>
    </div>
</p>`

You could still make this work by using `$('#formID').submit();` or `$.ajax()` in your click function.

http://jsfiddle.net/hAAwk/1/

Comment: Awesome work Jamie! The <button> tag really seemed to be the issue there. thanks for helping me out. Up next I'm planning to make the lid lift off the trashcan when the first click is made.

Comment: Sounds pretty sweet, I'd like to see that in action. Nice work on the buttons too.

Comment: Here's the final result! I wonder what you think of it...
http://jsfiddle.net/myyn5/232/

I found this handy Jquery UI effect called SwitchClass! This made things a lot easier... As you can see it's now possible to do animations on css selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/myyn5/67/)

```
$(function() {

    $(".custom").on({
        click: function() {
            event.preventDefault(); //  Show span
            if (!$(this).hasClass('confirm')) {
                $("span").show();
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    width: 90 + 'px',
                }, 700, function() {
                    $("span").animate({
                        left: '+=22',
                        opacity: 1
                    }, 500, 'swing');
                    $(this).addClass("confirm");
                    $(this).removeClass("custom");
                })
            } else {

                $(this).removeClass("confirm");
                $("span").stop().animate({
                    left: '-15px',
                    opacity: 0
                }, 500, 'swing', function() {
                    $(".custom").animate({
                        width: 36 + 'px'
                    }, 500);
                });
                $(this).addClass("custom");
            }
        }

    });
});​
```